# process.start > mail to to open default mail error (winforms c#)

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm new to WinForms and I want to open the default mail of the windows but I'm getting this error.

Does anyone know the reason?

[image]

Comment: have you tried executing that command from your local terminal? AFAIK, `mailto` is something that browsers support - not command lines.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann I don't think that's true. On my system opening a command prompt and typing `start mailto:a@b.com` opens Outlook

Comment: @CaiusJard okay, didn't know that. but does `Process.Start` support the same feature?

Comment: I don't think there's a difference between the two.. I don't recall using a mailto in Process.Start recently but I use http urls often, and it's the same handling mechanism AFAIK

Answer (score 0):

Possibly the `mailto` url handler settings on your system are messed up. Take a look in `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Associations\URLAssociations\MAILTO\Userchoice` or open the Default Apps control panel applet and ensure your email handler is set to a valid, installed program

[image]

As an aside, I've never seen `[at]` used in place of `@` in mailto URLs.. `mailto:user@host.com?Subject=Hello world` should work out fine:

[image]

(On the right is windows Mail)